# How can I solve this recursion?

Tags: recursion

What is the best way to solve this recursion in Mathematica?

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really want to do but you can try by using

```
a[n_,i_,j_]:=Sum[k*a[n,k,j]*(n-1),{k,1,(n-i+j)}]
```

I would recommend you to read the 4th point of https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/
where they do the Fibonacci recursion.

Remember that when n=1 the sum will be equal to zero so be careful if you think that the code is not working.

so if we use n=2, i=1, j=1, you should get

```
a[2,1,1]= a[2,1,1]+2 a[2,2,1]
```

I add the n index in both a[] definitions so all the a[] parameters will have the same number of indexes.

The problem here is that in this code you have to make sure that n> -i+j or you get only zero.

Comment: I don't think that `k*a[n,k,j]*(n-1)` is what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the following code is what you want:

```
ClearAll[a];
a[{_, _}, 0] = 1;
a[{i_, j_}, n_] := a[{i, j}, n] =
   Sum[ k*a[{k, j}, n - 1], {k, 1, n - i + j}];
Table[ {n, Table[
      a[{i, j}, n], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 4}]
   }, {n, 1, 3}]
```

Here, `a[{i,j},n]` corresponds to your $\,a_{ij}(n).$
I added some needed initial condition $\,a_{ij}(0)=1\,$
but you can change it if you need to.